# How to get last item from array (reverse array) Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am using the `FILTER` formula to get filtered data

```
=FILTER(A:H,REGEXMATCH(D:D,"......"))
```

This function returns multiple results from top to bottom of my document.

I need to get the last result from filter function.

How can I achieve this?

I have already tried to transpose, reverse array, etc. But didn't get desired result.

I would be grateful for any help with this matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the contribution of ttarchala, maybe this will also work

```
=INDEX(A:H,MATCH(2,IF(regexmatch(D:D, "..."),1),1))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works great !!! Could you explain how does this work ?

Comment: I'm also flummoxed, in my test worksheet the match() result is always 1 which as an argument ot index() would normally give the first row, not the last one... yet it still works, how?

Comment: OK I figured it out... by putting the match() inside an index() we enforce an array context, like putting the match() inside arrayformula(), and in this context the match()'s result is indeed the last row, not the first one.  It's a neat trick to know, but a really opaque one too.

Comment: Also note that binary search (more info here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) in an array seems to ignore boolean values in Google Sheets.

Answer (score 1):

```
=index(
   filter(<your_range>, <your_condition>),
   rows(filter(<your_range>, <your_condition>))
 )
```

The disadvantage is that you have to repeat the filter parameters twice, maybe someone can improve on this answer?